# Changing the background of an input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm unable to find the error. When updating the background of the entry, it does not match the value of the entry.

I want, when the value is **"true"** the background is **green**, and when the value is **"false"** the background is **red**.

```js
function color() {
  if ((document.getElementById('ID').value = 'true')) {
    document.getElementById('ID').style.color = '#FFF';
    document.getElementById('ID').style.background = 'green';
  } else if ((document.getElementById('ID').value = 'false')) {
    document.getElementById('ID').style.color = '#FFF';
    document.getElementById('ID').style.background = 'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ID" value="false" onchange="color();">
```

Comment: @Shree I put onchange = "color ();" ..... is it correct?

Comment: In JavaScript, `=` is an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment). To compare, use a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators) like `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You forgot to call the function `color()`.
2. Compare your if condition with `==`.

   `=` The JavaScript operator assigns a value to the left operand based on the value of the right operand.

   `==` operator is an equality operator. It checks whether its two operands are the same or not.

   You can also use `===`

   `===` strict equality comparison operator. It returns false for values that are not of the same kind. For equality, this operator performs type casting.

Run below snippet for demo.

```js
color()
function color() {
  if (document.getElementById('ID').value == 'true') {
    document.getElementById('ID').style.color = "#FFF";
    document.getElementById('ID').style.background = "green";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ID').style.color == "#FFF";
    document.getElementById('ID').style.background = "red";
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ID" value="true" onchange="color()">
```

Comment: Re (1), it's assigned in the html via the onchange property, although it doesn't need the paratheses.

Answer (score 0):

replace onchange to [onkeyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event)

```js
// onload
color();

// keyup  event 
function color() {
  let e = document.getElementById('ID');
  let value = e.value;
  let bg = '';
  let txt = '';
  
  if(value == 'true'){
    bg = 'green';
    txt = '#FFF';
  }
  
   if(value == 'false'){
    bg = 'red';
    txt = '#FFF';
  }
  
  e.style.color = txt;
  e.style.background = bg;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ID" value="false" onkeyup="color();">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function color() {
            var inputId = document.getElementById('ID');
                inputId.style.color = '#ffffff';
              if (inputId.value =='true' ) {                
                    inputId.style.backgroundColor = "green";
              } else {
                    inputId.style.backgroundColor = "red";
              }
              
        };
        
        color();
```